# Maple system of equations in matrix

Tags: systems-of-equations, maple

I have three matrices A, B and C. Set of equations like this:

$A\cdot B=C$

And I know what A and C are, but I'm looking for B.

Sorry for beginner question, but I'm trying to do this entire noon and don't have a clue. Just got maple license from uni today.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ is invertible (I.E. $\det(A) \neq 0 $) you can find the inverse $A^{-1}$ such that $A^{-1}A = I$. Then you will have $B=A^{-1}C$

The commands in Maple are Det(A); and Inverse(A);

Comment: I actually did this like that, but I was curious if there's the way to make this without $A^{-1}$.

Comment: Of the top of my head this is the best way to go about it if $A$ is invertible. You might look at the documentation for [LinearSolve](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=LinearAlgebra%2fLinearSolve) but I didn't try it out myself.

Comment: It can be done as **B:= LinearAlgebra:-LinearSolve(A,C)**. This does it without computing $A^{-1}$ and is generally considered more numerically robust.